# Sed not working as expected in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, sed

I am using below sed command in bash

```
echo "<version>1.0.216</version>" | sed  -e 's@<version>\(.*\)</version>@\1@'
```

which when run gives me below output

```
  -bash-4.1$  echo "<version>1.0.216</version>" | sed  -e 's@<version>\(.*\)</version>@\1@'
  1.0.216
```

But when I put the same command in a ruby file(content below)

```
"value=`echo "<version>1.0.216</version>" | sed  -e 's@<version>\(.*\)</version>@\1@'`
```

puts value"

I get this output

```
     -bash-4.1$ ruby test.rb
     <version>1.0.216</version>
```

Can anyone help me in understanding what might be causing this behavior. I am thinking this might be issue with the way ruby handles regex but my search for regex for ruby did not yield any results.

Comment: do your try to escape the `"` of your echo content or use `$()` instead of `\`\``

Comment: You mean something like this 


input = "<version>1.0.216</version>"


value=$(echo "#{input}" | sed  -e 's@<version>\(.*\)

</version>@\1@')


This one didnt work as well.

Comment: `"value=$( echo "<version>1.0.216</version>" | sed  -e 's@<version>\(.*\)</version>@\1@' )"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"value=$( echo "<version>1.0.216</version>" | sed -e 's@<version>\([^<]*\)</version>@\1@' )"
# or, due to shell escaping interpretation (note the double \\)
"value=$( echo "<version>1.0.216</version>" | sed -e 's@<version>\\([^<]*\\)</version>@\\1@' )"
```

or

```
"value=$( echo "<version>1.0.216</version>" | sed -e 's/.*>//;s/<.*//' )"
#for a multi line entry
"value=$( StreamOfYourData | sed -n -e '/<version>/ {s/.*>//;s/<.*//p;q;}' )"
```

Comment: the second one works,but rest all aren't working.Can you help me in understanding what is so unique about double \\ and why it work in ruby scripts?

Comment: the shell interpret the content at different level, ex transform the variable by the content of it. in this case the interpretation of `\\` mean in direct shell command `\\` where in subshell of ruby escape the next character, so `\( ` is interpreted and become `(` loosing the meaning in next level (sed action). By escaping the `\\ `, it change the level of escaping so `\\(` become `\(` at the sed level and have the good meaning.